# There is no CNTK command

Tags: cntk

I am a newbee to cntk. I followed this page https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/Setup-CNTK-on-your-machine to install cntk in my windows 8.1 system. However, after successfully installed cntk-2.0.beta15.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl I can't run cntk from cmd.The prompt shows there is no such command.

I ran a quick test and believed cntk was successfully installed as shown below.

```
F:\Anaconda3\Lib>python -c "import cntk; print(cntk.__version__)"
2.0.beta15.0
```

I searched cntk.exe in %Anaconda3_HOME%\Scripts but nothing found. Is there any additional steps I need to take before I can run cntk in my command line(I am just trying to go through the tutorial in https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/Tutorial)? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The page you reference (https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/Setup-CNTK-on-your-machine) is the install-entry page, listing various install options. At the top of the page, it explains the quick installation steps to install CNTK into a python environment. If you run only the top 'whl-download instructions', CNTK is only installed into a python environment, there won't be a CNTK.exe since CNTK (dlls and libraries) are used from inside python, no cntk.exe required.

If you want to run CNTK in a stand alone fashion, you should use the 'Script Driven Installation' from this page: https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/Setup-Windows-Binary-Script

thx
Wolfgang

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the "\cntk\Scripts\cntkpy35.bat" script from the console from which you want to run cntk commands. It sets up the environment for cntk.

I created shortcut on my desktop with this as a Target, so it sets up environment automatically when console opens:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k "C:\CNTK\CNTK-2-0-beta15-0-Windows-64bit-GPU-1bit-SGD\cntk\Scripts\cntkpy35.bat"
```

But in order for this shortcut to work you need to delete the next check from cntkpy35.bat:

```
if /I "%CMDCMDLINE%" neq ""%COMSPEC%" " (
    echo.
    echo Please execute this script from inside a regular Windows command prompt.
    echo.
    exit /b 0
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution can be using python3. I had the same problem in linux. So i downloaded the python3 version and it worked. For Linux it would be

pip3 install cntk